# role of _ and array reduction

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a code example using jsx and redux to set the reducer as follows:

```
       case Test:
        const { [action.payload.id]: _, ...filteredAlerts } = state.alerts;

        return {
            ...state,
            ...{ 
                alerts:
                {
                    ...filteredAlerts
                }
            }
        };
    default:
        return state;
```

Everything works fine but I do not understand this line at all:

```
 const { [action.payload.id]: _, ...filteredAlerts } = state.alerts;
```

Can anyone provide a simple and clear explanation on that?
For example what does _ mean here?

```
[action.payload.id]: _
```

and what does this line do?

```
const { [action.payload.id]: _, ...filteredAlerts } = state.alerts;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All it's doing is assigning a certain item in `state.alerts` to a local variable with the name `_`, then collecting the rest of the items with  `...`. Essentially, this is copying all the properties in `state.alerts` *except* `action.payload.id` to the new `filteredAlerts` variable. It's a long form of writing this:

```
let filteredAlerts = {};

for (let key in state.alerts) {
    if (key != "action.payload.id") {
        filteredAlerts[key] = state.alerts[key];
    }
}
```

Except you can still access the `action.payload.id` with `_`.

Comment: Just curious...usually _ is lodash... is there a particular reason why the example code is using _ as the local variable name?

Comment: No particular reason - with the exception of Lodash and Underscore, it's used as a general "ignore this variable" name. (Unless the variable has a name and just starts with an underscore like `_id` - then it's kind of like "this is automatic/readonly/sensitive/important - don't directly modify it").

Comment: Thanks. So this means that the code has a hidden for loop in it? is this code style a es6 feature?

Comment: Ok, and the only other question I have is...in your block of code, there should be an `else` block to explain the short form, right? I.e., `else { action.payload.id = _}`?

Comment: @HamedMinaee It is an ES6 feature, and yes, it most likely has a loop to collect all the properties.

Comment: I think the last comment is very important too (and helpful). This is not specific to jsx or redux... it's ES6.